# How to use Content provider without database and share data to another application

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to share and receive data at some point from one application to another application, what's the best way to do?

I see `content provider` is used with database but I have only few strings to share to another applications. I have data stored in
SHARED PREFERENCES, which other application needs to access and vice-versa.

Please provide suggestions.

TIA.

Comment: while(TIA) sleep();

Comment: Hmmm.. You still no answers possible..

Comment: @blackapps What do you mean?

Comment: We are here for a thank afterwards if helped to satisfaction. Not in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MatrixCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor).You can populate `MatrixCursor` with data. From official doc

> A mutable cursor implementation backed by an array of Objects. Use
> newRow() to add rows. Automatically expands internal capacity as
> needed.

`newRow()` `addRow()` method will help you to add columnValues

Here is sample code

```
try (MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"id", "title"})) {
    cursor.addRow(new String[] { "1", "Book 1" });
    cursor.addRow(new String[] { "2", "Book 2" });

    cursor.newRow()
            .add("id", "3")
            .add("title", "Book 3");
} catch (Exception ignored) {

}
```